# Ansible - environment variables in file lookups

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible tasks that copies the key from the local user to the remote machine:

```
authorized_key: user=deployer key="{{ lookup('file', '/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

I want to user variable instead of **my_user**.  Enviernoment vairble (i.e. `lookup('env', 'DEPLOY_KEY_PATH')` or in fact any variable.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current user key, you can of course use the `~` alias. This will work:

```
authorized_key: state=present user=deployer key="{{ lookup('file', '~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Also, note that `state=present` may not be mandatory, but [it is a good practice to keep it](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#always-mention-the-state).

---

Then, although it depends on what is your project exactly, I do not advise you to do it this way for three reasons:

1. You might need to add several public keys.
2. You might need to add public of other users.
3. If a user start your ansible playbook in a specific environment, this behavior may be unwanted or dangerous.

This is what I suggest you to do.

Add a `files/sshkeys/my_user.pub` file at the root of your project, and paste any public keys you want inside this file. Pubkeys rarely change, so it’s not likely to be a problem to maintain this file.

```
├── files
│   └── sshkeys
│       └──my_user.pub
├── hosts
└── site.yml
```

You can look for the key file using the authorized_key module:

```
authorized_key: state=present user=deployer key="{{ lookup('file', './files/sshkeys/my_user.pub') }}"
```

Alternatively, as you asked, if you use a variable:

```
authorized_key: state=present user=deployer key="{{ lookup('file', './files/sshkeys/'+ user.name +'.pub') }}"
```